# "Industry sources" meaning

Tags: meaning

### I don't really understand the meaning of this term in this text: **"Industry sources"** please aware me thanks

Details of the agreement have yet to be made public, but **industry sources** have said Noble and Delek will be allowed to keep control of Leviathan, the world's largest offshore gas discovery of the past decade. The government's decision makes use of Article 52 of the Antitrust Law, allowing them to circumvent the antitrust regulator and approve the agreement with the gas companies. The only member of the government to oppose the deal has been Minister of Environmental Protection Avi Gabay. "The state must listen and understand the companies' claims and demands and then utilize its authority and sovereignty on this matter in order to arrive at the plan that is best for the citizens of Israel," said Gabay.

Comment: His undisclosed contacts within the industry being discussed.

Comment: This is journalistic language. Newspaper articles usually like to name their sources, e.g. "President Trump has stated that the wall is necessary."  However if  the person who made a statement is not famous enough to be mentioned (or if the person wants to stay anonymous) then they just say they received the information from "a source".

Answer (score 1):

Source ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/source))

> one that supplies information

"Industry sources" simply refers to informants in the (oil and gas) industry